# How to Access DOM in a Python thread or subprocess

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading

I'm trying to update an epub reader to deal with media overlays. There are two things to be done: play the audio of the overlay, and simultaneously highlight the text being read. Playing the audio was not hard. I used the pydub module to chop up mp3 or mp4 files and play them sequentially. For displaying the content of the epub, I use the WebKit.Webview from the gi.repository. This gives access to the DOM document, and allows one to tinker with the elements it contains. Alternatively, I can achieve the same effect using Javascript.

But, although this works in the main thread of execution, it doesn't in another thread, or even in another process, if I fork from the main process.
To illustrate the problem, I tried this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def on_access_dom(self, widget, data=None):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Process(target=self.jsdom)
        p.start()
        p.join()
    #self.jsdom()


def jsdom(self):
    cmd = '''node = document.getElementById("f003");
       node.innerHTML="<span style='color: red'>red text</span>"; '''
    self.viewer.execute_script(cmd)
```

The idea is just to show the text in red. I would later use the colour specified in the css for the epub. Above I use javascript. Alternatively I can replace the function jsdom by

```
def trydom(self):
    dom = self.domdoc
    text_id = 'f003'
    node = dom.get_element_by_id(text_id)
    text = node.get_outer_html()
    angle = text.find('>')
    start = text[:angle]+' style="color: red">'
    text = text[angle+1:]
    node.set_outer_html(start+text)
```

Now if instead of starting a new process or a new thread, I run either jsdom or trydom directly in the main thread. it all works as desired. But in a new thread or process nothing happens.

Am I missing something? I don't see how the GIL could be the culprit, as it should apply to threads, but not to forked processes.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found at
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading

My function trydom is unchanged. However, on_access_dom now looks like

```
def on_access_dom(self, widget, data=None):
    red = threading.Thread(target=self.wrap_trydom, daemon=True)
    red.start()
```

along with

```
def wrap_trydom(self):
    GLib.idle_add(self.trydom)
```

My problem was that I had not learned that Gtk doesn't like you to access the UI directly from threads that are not the one with the main event loop. The idle_add function lets you do this by executing your code while the main event loop is idle.

I hope this answer is useful for other people. It has let me get on with my main task of developing an epub reader that supports media overlays.